# How to use netcat to check ports on more than one remote server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, networking, netcat

I have the following lines in a script file to wait until port 1521 is open in server1 AND server2 are open and then execute start_apps.sh script.

How can I modify this to wait until port 1521 is open in either one of the servers (server1 OR server2) and then execute the start_apps.sh script?

```
until (nc -z  server1 1521); do echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') wait for server1";done
until (nc -z server2 1521); do echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T') wait for server2"; done
start_apps.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop that does non-blocking checks. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]; do
    if [ $(nc -z server1 1521) ] || [ $(nc -z server2 1521) ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1 # if desired
done
start_apps.sh
```

This loop will run until either condition is met.